# How to get xp_pcre to run on a 64 bit system?

Tags: sql-server, regex

For many years we have been using xp_pcre for regular expressions in sql server:

[xp_pcre - Regular Expressions in T-SQL](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/xp_pcre.aspx)

I've just migrated to a new 64 bit vista development machine and have installed xp pcre.  Unfortunately when i try to use the sprocs I get the following error: Could not load the DLL xp_pcre.dll, or one of the DLLs it references. Reason: 193(%1 is not a valid Win32 application.).

Has anyone had any success installing xp_pcre on a 64 bit machine running vista?  Any advice?  Thanks in advance,
Shane

Comment: FWIW - after wrestling with the outdated xp_pcre project and the boost c++ libraries (that it references) for half a day without success...we've decided to abandon xp_pcre on all our 64 bit servers and try to recreate the same interface using CLR User-Defined Functions.  
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Since it's a compiled DLL, you would probably have to recompile it to get a 64 bit DLL, that could be run on your 64 bit machine.  Since nothing at that page has been updated since 2005, it's unlikely there is an already a prebuilt version for 64 bit.  However, since the source code is included, you could, if you have VS for C++, with a 64 bit compiler, compile it yourself and try to get it working that way.